# number of positive real root of $f(x)=x^4+2x^3-2 , x\in \Bbb{R}$,

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)=x^4+2x^3-2 , x\in \Bbb{R}$,
(A) has two roots in $[0,\infty)$
(B) has three roots in $[0,\infty)$
(C) has no roots in $[0,\infty)$
(D) has a unique roots in $[0,\infty)$

---

How can I do this?I am stuck on it.

Comment: "(D)has `a` unique root `s` " ? Are you sure?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Descartes rule of sign it has at most one positive real root.Now $f(0)=-2$  and $f(1)=1$.so it has a real root between $0$ and $1$.so (D) is the correct option.